# "This app is not available for your phone" Facebook app error

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I've configured my Facebook app to use "Website with Facebook Login" and "App on Facebook", with the site URL and canvas URL both set to myapp.com (not the real URL).

I would like mobile devices to access the app through the App Center.  However, the App Detail page for my app (facebook.com/appcenter/myapp) displays the error "This app is not available for your phone", and the "Visit website" button is dulled and cannot be clicked (as tested on an iPhone and Galaxy Tab).  However, the app's canvas page (apps.facebook.com/myapp) displays myapp.com in an iframe within Facebook, just like in the desktop version.

Setting the "Mobile Site URL" in the "Mobile Web" section to myapp.com does not fix the error, but does redirect apps.facebook.com/myapp directly to myapp.com, instead of displaying myapp.com in an iframe.

Setting the "Mobile Site URL" to the canvas page (apps.facebook.com/myapp) also doesn't fix the error, and causes Facebook to report a redirect loop in the canvas page.

In summary, setting the "Mobile Site URL" to any of:

- blank
- the actual site (myapp.com)
- the canvas page (apps.facebook.com/myapp)

makes the App Detail page (facebook.com/appcenter/myapp) display the "This app is not available for your phone" error, but some combinations do allow the app to be accessed at the canvas page regardless of what this error says.  How can I get the App Detail page to let mobile users through to the canvas page, and not receive this error?

Edit: here is the current status of my app on the App Center:

[image]

This seems to imply that my App Detail page should be working on all devices, but perhaps it does not work for mobile users until it is listed in the App Center?  I'm not clear on the distinction.

Comment: Canvas and page tab apps are not available on the mobile version of Facebook (when your device gets redirected to m.facebook.com automatically) – that’s what the “Mobile Site URL” is for, so that users on such devices can visit your app _directly_, without the whole Facebook site around it – because Facebook doesn’t _want_ mobile devices to load the whole facebook.com page, because that’s quite traffic heavy and for full functionality might use more CPU/RAM resources than a “mobile device” might actually have.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for clarifying!  However, even when the "Mobile Site URL" is set to my actual site, I still get the error.  Any idea why that could be, or what I could reconfigure to avoid the error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under App Details -> Listed Platforms, "Mobile Web" needs to be set to "Display".  This is distinct from enabling the "Mobile Site URL" under Settings -> Select how your app integrates with Facebook, although I'm not aware of any situation in which you'd want to enable one of the two settings and disable the other.

Comment: i think now its in app center -> details